# MySQL Injection

Tags: penetration-test, sql-injection, mysql

The following line of vulnerable code makes the user input always upper case:

`mysql_query("select * from " . strtoupper($_GET['table']));`

In a scenario where MySQL's "lower_case_table_names" is set to 0 (case sensitive schema and table comparisons), I'm unable to read data from lowecase tables. Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: You can extract the actual name from the Schema information, (show tables) and use that in a union select.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser I've tried a lot of similar stuff without luck. How would I concatenate the name from information_schema to FROM? Can you please provide a working example?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but along these lines: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html

Comment: @SmokeDispenser I know where you are coming from, but I don't think it'll work. Whether we use union or sub-selects, at some point it's necessary to specify table name and since we cannot use any variables without a prepared statement, I don't see a way to bypass the upper case. I was thinking about collations (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html) or some modifiers that can force a case insensitive select

Comment: Duplicate of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169858/mysql-php-strtoupper-combination-bypass/169935