# Bypass PHP strtoupper() to perform SQL-injection on MySQL database?

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

I encountered a particularly weird situation where I have an SQL Injection vulnerability in the ORDER BY clause. The query is forged on backend and the injection payload is converted to upper case with the `strtoupper()` PHP function as can be seen bellow:

```
$sql="select something from table order by ".strtoupper($injection);
```

The problem is that I can extract from information_schema and variable names but I can't extract data from other tables because the table name in the select query is defined in lowercase.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user   -- Will work.
SELECT * FROM MYSQL.USER   -- Cannot find MYSQL.USER.
```

Apparently, `INFROMATION_SCHEMA` is the same thing as `information_schema`. But this does not apply to the other tables as well.

To extract data I used the following injection:

```
if(1=1,0,~0*2)
```

If the query returns true nothing happens, when is FALSE a generic message is revealed.

The MySQL server version is 5.7.19, the user is running as root but as I'v seen in the latest updates the server must be started with a special argument in order to use load_file or INTO OUTFILE statements.

I managed to sort of "bypass" the `strtoupper()` function by providing Cyrillic input characters but the MySQL does not recognize the table name because it's in Cyrillic.

Any advice on how to bypass this?

Comment: Crossstack see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive and possibly https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59407/how-to-make-mysql-table-name-case-insensitive-in-ubuntu

Comment: What Cyrillic input characters did you use to bypass the strtoupper() function?

Answer (score 0):

Use the sql CHAR() fonction for every character that needs to be lower case, put the whole request in a string using concat.

```
SET @T = CONCAT(CHAR(109),  CHAR(121),  [...]);
PREPARE A FROM @T;
EXECUTE A;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE A;
```

I tested it and it works well.

edit: showed the wrapping in proc

Comment: Can you show the entire injection? Because afaik this will not work, as `concat`/`char`/`lcase`/etc will not work on table names (it didn't work with my setup; do you have some specific version you are using?).

Comment: I was answering for the strtoupper() bypass, but there is some exec wrapping.Some people output a temporary script to a .sql file and then exec it back.

Comment: Chances are quite high that won't work, as almost everybody uses `mysqli_query`, `PDO::query` or similar which all doesn't allow multiple queries.

Comment: Unfortunately, stacked queries are not working. With this in mind, I can neither define variables nor procedures or functions. And the database engine/plugin used is InnoDB so all tables are lowercased. I think I'm out of luck with this one and need to try another attack vector.